# JSON: cargar datos por categoríaa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

¿Cómo puedo filtrar mediante `onclick` la data de cada categoría por ejemplo un botón llama a la categoría horror, y el otro botón a la categoría comedy. Gracias por la ayuda.

este es el JSON

```js
 {

 "data": [
    {
      "id": "e4462416-ee7b-4101-ac03-ae1025ee9e32",
      "title": "Devil At The Catacombs",
      "teaser": "Et porro recusandae labore cum labore esse aperiam. Aut id dolorum praesentium quidem eveniet optio quas cupiditate dolorem. Cupiditate vel animi nulla aspernatur nemo.",
      "categories": [
        "horror"
      ],
      "lang": [
        2,
        3
      ],
      "image": "image",
      "date_pub": "2/19/2017",
      "mode": [
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "b42fbd10-8b35-49b9-8b88-81e58e411576",
      "title": "Angels Without A Mouth",
      "teaser": "Autem et ab commodi dolor magni quo aspernatur cum aspernatur. Sed ullam blanditiis qui. Sequi saepe ut blanditiis architecto hic deserunt ullam et. Repellat quia earum ea eveniet facilis aperiam temporibus deleniti. Aliquam id voluptatem reprehenderit laudantium deleniti inventore rerum non culpa. Aut sint maxime illum quia.",
      "categories": [
        "horror"
      ],
      "lang": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "image": "image",
      "date_pub": "2/14/2017",
      "mode": [
        3
      ]
    },

{
      "id": "45ee0732-8968-4002-be7d-7fc99dbd718c",
      "title": "Companion Program",
      "teaser": "Blanditiis unde provident. Est consequuntur id quibusdam atque culpa magnam. Consequatur ut autem nisi velit consequatur qui dolor voluptates. Nesciunt totam suscipit sed ad minus officiis ipsa quo fuga. Ratione voluptatem asperiores quia qui voluptas et quae.",
      "categories": [
        "comedy"
      ],
      "lang": [
        2,
        1
      ],
      "image": "image",
      "date_pub": "8/21/2016",
      "mode": [
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6bc70195-ae44-47b3-9596-836a970cefe0",
      "title": "Jester Can Dance",
      "teaser": "Quis voluptates autem quidem. Eum itaque rerum veritatis perferendis earum rerum molestias soluta eum. Quia dolor autem ut corporis amet. Doloremque reiciendis quas. Eos voluptatibus voluptatem. Quos nisi ad voluptates enim voluptas nobis adipisci eaque sequi.",
      "categories": [
        "comedy"
      ],
      "lang": [
        2,
        3
      ],
      "image": "image",
      "date_pub": "2/19/2017",
      "mode": [
        1
      ]
    }
]

}
```

eventos boton

```
$.getJSON("/archivo.json",
  function(data) {

    $('#horror').on('click', function(){

        var projectHTML = '<ul id="resultado">';

$.each(data.data, function(i, item) {

    if (true)
    {
      projectHTML += '<li>';
        projectHTML += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
        projectHTML += '<span class="title">'+'<h3>' + item.title+ '</h3>'+'</span>';
        projectHTML += '<span class="description">'+'<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>'+'</span>';
        projectHTML += '</li>';
    }
}); //end each

projectHTML +='</ul>';
$('content').html(projectHTML);

    })
  })
```

Comment: Y cada título puede tener más de una categoría? Básicamente quieres filtrar entre elementos que tienen tags

Comment: si filtrar por tags, básicamente, se puede filtrar por tags, tiene categoría, horror, comedy, y tambien, lenguaje, el tag lang, también hay por idioma, tiene varias tags que se podría filtrar, básicamente quiero un ejemplo como filtraría si quiero hacerlo por cualquiera de los tags que tiene gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerte una función que recorra el array de películas y devuelva solamente aquellas que contengan determinado string en su array de categories.

Con eso sólo te falta hacer una función que genere N elementos a partir de un array de películas.

En el siguiente ejemplo sólo voy a llenar un `ul` con elementos `li` por cada película, y los botones usarán su atributo `value` para especificar a qué categoría se refieren.

```js
var data = {

 "data": [
    {
      "id": "e4462416-ee7b-4101-ac03-ae1025ee9e32",
      "title": "Devil At The Catacombs",
      "teaser": "Et porro recusandae labore cum labore esse aperiam. Aut id dolorum praesentium quidem eveniet optio quas cupiditate dolorem. Cupiditate vel animi nulla aspernatur nemo.",
      "categories": [
        "horror"
      ],
      "lang": [
        2,
        3
      ],
      "image": "image",
      "date_pub": "2/19/2017",
      "mode": [
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "b42fbd10-8b35-49b9-8b88-81e58e411576",
      "title": "Angels Without A Mouth",
      "teaser": "Autem et ab commodi dolor magni quo aspernatur cum aspernatur. Sed ullam blanditiis qui. Sequi saepe ut blanditiis architecto hic deserunt ullam et. Repellat quia earum ea eveniet facilis aperiam temporibus deleniti. Aliquam id voluptatem reprehenderit laudantium deleniti inventore rerum non culpa. Aut sint maxime illum quia.",
      "categories": [
        "horror"
      ],
      "lang": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "image": "image",
      "date_pub": "2/14/2017",
      "mode": [
        3
      ]
    },

{
      "id": "45ee0732-8968-4002-be7d-7fc99dbd718c",
      "title": "Companion Program",
      "teaser": "Blanditiis unde provident. Est consequuntur id quibusdam atque culpa magnam. Consequatur ut autem nisi velit consequatur qui dolor voluptates. Nesciunt totam suscipit sed ad minus officiis ipsa quo fuga. Ratione voluptatem asperiores quia qui voluptas et quae.",
      "categories": [
        "comedy"
      ],
      "lang": [
        2,
        1
      ],
      "image": "image",
      "date_pub": "8/21/2016",
      "mode": [
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6bc70195-ae44-47b3-9596-836a970cefe0",
      "title": "Jester Can Dance",
      "teaser": "Quis voluptates autem quidem. Eum itaque rerum veritatis perferendis earum rerum molestias soluta eum. Quia dolor autem ut corporis amet. Doloremque reiciendis quas. Eos voluptatibus voluptatem. Quos nisi ad voluptates enim voluptas nobis adipisci eaque sequi.",
      "categories": [
        "comedy"
      ],
      "lang": [
        2,
        3
      ],
      "image": "image",
      "date_pub": "2/19/2017",
      "mode": [
        1
      ]
    }
]

}

function filtrar_por_categoria(peliculas,categoria) {
    var matches=[];
    peliculas.forEach(function(pelicula) {
       if(pelicula.categories.indexOf(categoria)!==-1) {
         matches.push(pelicula);
       }
    });
    return matches;
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  jQuery('.filtro').click(function() {
     var categoria=jQuery(this).val();
     var peliculas = filtrar_por_categoria(data.data,categoria);
     jQuery('#peliculas').empty();
     peliculas.forEach(function(pelicula) {
        var li_pelicula = jQuery('<li>'+pelicula.title+'</li>');
        jQuery('#peliculas').append(li_pelicula);
     });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="filtro" value="horror">Horror</button>
<button class="filtro" value="comedy">Comedy</button>

<ul id="peliculas">

</ul>
```

Para tu caso específico, que no se puede reproducir en un snippet (debido a la petición json y a que no conozco el resto de tu DOM, debiera ser:

```
function filtrar_por_categoria(peliculas,categoria) {
    var matches=[];
    peliculas.forEach(function(pelicula) {
       if(pelicula.categories.indexOf(categoria)!==-1) {
         matches.push(pelicula);
       }
    });
    return matches;
}

$.getJSON("/archivo.json", function(data) {

    $('#horror').on('click', function() {

      var projectHTML = '<ul id="resultado">';
      var peliculas_de_horror = filtrar_por_categoria(data.data,'horror');
      $.each(peliculas_de_horror, function(i, item) {
        projectHTML += '<li>';
        projectHTML += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
        projectHTML += '<span class="title">'+'<h3>' + item.title+ '</h3>'+'</span>';
        projectHTML += '<span class="description">'+'<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>'+'</span>';
        projectHTML += '</li>';
    }); //end each

    projectHTML +='</ul>';
    $('content').html(projectHTML);

    });
  });
```

Comment: me cambias mucho mi estructura y se me complica no debo tocar el JSON y necesito hacerlo en base a lo que ya tengo armado. Gracias

Comment: la parte del HTML la tienes que hacer tú y es trivial. Lo importante es el uso de la función `filtrar_por_categoria` para operar sobre un subconjunto de `data.data`

Comment: ya lo tengo construido, si te das cuenta esta armada esa es la estructura que esta corriendo ya en el proyecto no la puedo modificar si te das cuenta en el each.data funciona pero carga todo el contenido pero de todas las categorías lo que quiero es solo filrar por categoría, habra que cambiar la forma de llamar a data, filtrando por el string correspondiente respetando mi estructura algo debo estar  haciendo mal pero no pudo cambiar la forma de mi HTML debe quedar tal cual, como lo planteas tengo que modificar mucho debo respetar lo ya armado es así tal cual esta me dejo entender

Comment: fíjate en mi HTML construido arriba debe quedar así tal cual, solo debe variar la información llamando a la categoría correspondiente en realidad las categorías cargan las mismas propiedades debe respetar ese formato. Gracias

Comment: Ya te dije como hacerlo, ahora te toca a ti usar mi función justo antes de aplicar el jquery.each. No voy a hacer la tarea completa

Comment: hola gracias por la ayuda, no estoy pidiendo que lo hagas solo que me guíes, pero en tu código o ejemplo que dejas me cambias mi estructura, yo no puedo tocar el JSON, tu lo modificas, usa <buttons> y le das nombres y values, yo utilizo <li> y los genero dinámico no puestos en el HTML entonces tu ejemplo no es que este mal si no que no se adapta a lo que tengo, tendría que cambiar todo lo que ya arme para hacerlo como tu lo pones. espero se entienda.

Comment: En realidad no estoy tocando el JSON. Lo que pasa es que para que funcione el snippet, tengo que ponerlo en duro como un objeto, ya que no hay forma de hacer que la petición ajax funcione si no es en tu aplicación. Voy a editar mi respuesta a ver si te ayuda un poco

Comment: gracias funciono a la perfección, disculpa pero recien le entro a lo del JSON y entender los objetos arrays y propiedades, ya lo entiendo pero a un me cuesta en ciertos proyectos complejos igual por eso existe este tipo de comunidades, para darse la mano gracias por todo.

Comment: Marca la pregunta como respondida si todo funcionó, así le puede servir a alguien más